# Upload file one by one in Struts 2

Tags: jsp, file-upload, jboss, struts2

In my Struts 2 application. I use `<s:file>` for file upload. But when I start uploading, the server (Jboss) uploads all files to `temp` location using maximum bandwidth.

I want to upload files one by one.

Is there any possible way in Struts to do this or suggest me any other possible way for this.

Answer (score 0):

Create a button type submit for each file upload input control. Wrap it with the form tag. Each form for each file. Make sure you didn't use `multiple` attribute. Otherwise it will allows to use multiple files per single input. Then when you submit a form which belong a single button you only submitted the single file. You can also remove the input control once the button is clicked and the form is submitted.

```
<s:iterator begin="1" end="5"> 
 <s:form action="fileUpload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  Enter file: <input name="upload" type="file"/>
  <s:submit/>
 </s:form>
</s:iterator>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. In my case, hundred number of files to be upload. Because of that I can't use several file upload for that.

Comment: Ex:- 200 users, 100 file for one user, if all users try at the same time. There can be a network problem. Because of that I have to upload file one by one

Comment: This form doesn't allow you to upload more than one file at the time you submit the one file for upload. Several buttons use the same destination but you can disable some buttons for the sake of response notifying you about download progress. Once you have done to download then you send response  to the user waiting for the next button to reopen. At the same time you can remove the button that worked.

Comment: But It's not possible users to select file one by one. Because they have hundred number of file to upload. I use multiple file upload. can I send user selected multiple files one by one to server.

Comment: Sure you can, just write the code that will submit all of the form one by one.